# Remote debugging (dev server is remote in a different network) with Xdebug and PhpStorm not connecting

Tags: php, magento, phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug my dev environment which is in a different network from my localhost with PhpStorm and Xdebug. I tried many things but couldn't find the fix.

Below is my `php.ini` file settings:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.101
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="XDEBUG_ECLIPSE"
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

As my dev server and debugging environment is different, I have provided my local system IP address.

Xdebug logs give below error:

> I: Checking remote connect back address.
>   I: Remote address found, connecting to 192.168.1.1:9000.
>   E: Could not connect to client. :-(

Is this issue coming because my local and dev server belongs to different network?

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect from your host machine to PHPSTORM

```
nc -vz 192.168.1.1 9000
```

If success try the same from dev
If it fails from dev the yes its because dev machine in other network

Comment: so what could be an alternate solution for it?

Comment: Dev machine its docker on host?

Comment: no.it's a simple linux machine which has public IP.no docker configurations

Comment: You need port forwarding
`ssh -L 9000:localhost:9000 dev`  
Replace dev to ip of your dev machine

Comment: Sorry -R
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-debugging-via-ssh-tunnel.html

Comment: my local system is windows and the dev server is linux .so you mean connect to the dev server(linux) and run the port forwarding command Or you want me to run port forwarding from my local system...

Comment: If your host have ssh server you can try `ssh -L 9000:localhost:9000 host` from dev else read section in the docs "To set up an SSH tunnel on Windows"

Comment: I have already done the tunneling(both options),but no success with that.

Comment: Did you try `nc -vz 192.168.1.1:9000` from host machine?

Comment: Probably PHPStorm doesn't listen 9000 port. Try `nc -vz localhost:9000`

Comment: I have done the PHP storm setup to listen to port 9000.Mind connecting over my system to have a look and help me out.

Comment: I tried nc -vz localhost:9000 from my dev server  and got the error: connection refused

Comment: Did you try it on host machine?

Comment: Yes..I did the same.Can we connect via screen sharing where you can look into the issue and help me out.That would be really nice.

Comment: Sorry I don't have time for it. And it doesn't help to the community

Comment: If you can't connect to 9000 port from host machine problem not in network but in no listeners on 9000 port. You should check if any process listen the port, if yes it should be PHPStorm

Comment: my local port 9000 is listening for PHP storm.Still issues with the remote connection

Comment: Sorry I gave you wrong format for nc command. Correct format is`nc -vz localhost 9000`. The command try scan your 9000 port and if it fails then no listeners on the port.

Comment: How you've checked that PHPStorm listen 9000 port?

Comment: now i have moved the code locally(ubuntu),now my debug session is getting connected,but my page keeps loading till infinite..page loading never stops..what could be the probable reason for the same?

Comment: any update to my last comment would be great @matchish